# Старайтесь не использовать безымянные объекты с настраиваемым созданием и уничтожением (es.84)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

Имеется метод у класса, который по сути задает название класса окна, но это не обязательный параметр, и я его задал как:

```
void some_func(const ::std::wstring& some = {L"some value"})
{
   ...
}
```

Но при компиляции, получаю предупреждение:

> C26444    Старайтесь не использовать безымянные объекты с настраиваемым
>   созданием и уничтожением (es.84).

Если он не обязателен, то как его еще то задать? Почему этот код не нравится компилятору от Microsoft?

**P.S. Имя то у объекта имеется... И сам объект  используется**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не понял почему кто-то проголосовал за закрытие, минимальный код есть, и описание тоже есть.

Comment: "*минимальный код есть*" - [mcve] отсутствует. даже если кусок кода из вопроса дописать с попробовать собрать, то заявленное поведение не воспроизводится.

Comment: @VTT, если не воспроизводится, то посмотрите на скриншот, думаю что этого будет достаточно ;)

Comment: *"думаю что этого будет достаточно"* - тогда я думаю вам будет достаточно если я пришлю скриншот, где оно не воспроизводится... хз, может у вас выпуск студии старый. Еще там висит непонятный префикс `_Ptr:` - это откуда?

Comment: @VTT: Префикс показывает решарпер.

Comment: Это VS 2019 16.3.9?

Comment: Да, это VS 16.3.9

Comment: С одной стороны, сообщение совершенно правильное - безымянный объект у вас есть. С другой стороны - в данном случае оно неуместно. Обычная ложная тревога.

Answer (score 2):

Компилятор не прав.

[ES.84 (Core Guidelines)](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es84-dont-try-to-declare-a-local-variable-with-no-name) говорит про локальные переменные, например

```
std::wstring{L"some"};
```

А тут совсем другой случай, хотя значение параметра по-умолчанию это тоже временная локальная переменная, она будет жить дольше времени работы функции, и на неё ссылается аргумент функции.

Comment: В общем случае можно считать багом, верно?

Comment: А как вам удалось воспроизвести такую проблему?